# Implement custom components from javascript in Django

Tags: javascript, css, django

My company has provided various custom developed components for web development (buttons, icons etc). The instructions they give for using them is via JavaScript loading CSS files for each element.

I have my local Django project setup with

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
```

I tried putting their "loader.js" script as a  tag in my Django template, but still can't seem to use their custom elements.  I got so desperate to use them that I navigated to each individual components' CSS file and adapted it to regular HTML components (submit button, etc).

I'm sure part of the problem is my novice level understanding of all this, but I'd like to think I could figure it out.

Apologies if I haven't provided enough details for this to make sense.  If any other details are needed I will add them.

More detail:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I tried to follow the Django tutorial as much as possible so my folder stucture should match what the have on the site, but here's how I have it:

- MachineUtilization

  - migrations
  - static

    - node_modules

      - company

        - web_components

          - dist

            - index.js
            - rotor.js (company style name)
            - loader

              - index.js
  - templates
  - apps.py
  - urls.py
  - models.py
  - etc...

In one of my templates I have the following code

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'company\web_components\dist\loader\index.js' %}"></script>
```

In their "installation example for javascript they have the following:

```
import { defineCustomElements } from 'company/web_components/dist/loader'

defineCustomElements(window)
```

Maybe part (if not all) of the problem is this is node.js.  I'm not really sure Django and node.js can play well together.

Comment: Show more code. What's your `BASE_DIR`, `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT` and how is your folder structure? Where are you putting `loader.js`? How are you trying to load it in your HTML file? Are you loading static and using Django's template language?

Comment: @Stephen edited my question. Sorry for the lack of detail